# How can I create push notifications to a phone application from a server for a single targeted phone (cross platform)?

Tags: push-notification, cross-platform

So my requirements in mind are I have an application continuously running on a phone and I need to be able to push events to this application from time to time.

The application will primarily pull data from the server but sometimes the server will have urgent data it needs to send to the phone.  I also have as a requirement to send the notification to a very specific phone, which the application will have a unique identifier associated with that phone.  So I'm not looking for a simple broadcast solution.

Polling a web service by the application on a frequent time interval seems like it would impact a data plan too much, plus battery usage of the device.  So I'd like to avoid a polling solution if possible.

What would be a good way to accomplish this?

Comment: What platforms are we talking about? Can you be more specific?

Comment: IOS, Android and Windows Phone ideally.

Comment: check out Parse: https://parse.com/products/push

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not quite understand if you want to build the application yourself or if you are looking for one.

I use [Pushover](https://pushover.net) to do this. Pushover runs on Android, iPhone, iPad, and Desktop. It supports multiple message priorities. You can do a http POST with a unique ID and message to send a message to a unique device.

Pushover has it's own API and is really easy to use.

Comment: Can you integrate pushover messages with your application and bundle it so that it doesn't have to be a separate download?

Comment: I have no clue. I only used it as a separate download. I use it allot in combination with www.ifttt.com

Answer (score 6):

I recently used PubNub to send push notifications to a web app in lieu of Web Sockets. PubNub has SDKs for all sorts of languages. Their long polling method is extremely fast and efficient. You can map messages to different devices based on the UUID of the channel. At first it seems like a simple broadcast solution (and Pubnub can be used this way), but we were able to create unique sessions with a relative amount of ease.

http://www.pubnub.com/developers/

Answer (score 0):

Polling can indeed be costly in terms of data and battery. The most efficient way to send data from the server to a phone is using Push Notifications (iOS) or Google Cloud Messaging (Android). Both notification types can be implemented directly by the developer or by making use of an API.

[Golgi](http://www.golgi.io) is an SDK that produces custom type safe communication APIs. The APIs produced have full support for both Push Notifications and Google Cloud Messaging.